# How to make ApiMember work when working with dotnet core

Tags: servicestack, .net-core

Lately I've been trying to make use of the metadata page to be part of our effort to make our documentation more responsive. I found that ApiMember somehow doesn't seems to work with projects using dotnet core.

This is my DTO, updated to include the full content of the dto definition

```
using ServiceStack;

[Api("Test request")]
[Route("/test/{Input}","GET")]
[Route("/test")]
public class TestRequest:IReturn<TestResponse>
{
    [ApiMember(Name="Parameter name", Description = "Parameter Description", 
    ParameterType = "body", DataType = "string", IsRequired = true)]
    public string Input { get; set; }
}
public class TestResponse
{
    public string Output { get; set; }
}
//Validator
public class TestRequestValidator : AbstractValidator<TestRequest>
{
    public TestRequestValidator()
    {
        RuleFor(r => r.Input).NotEmpty();
    }
}
```

And I expect the Name and Description should show up in the metadata page, it doesn't. What should I do?

And, if I may ask a 2nd question, since I have the full dto, I must ask the validator (using fluentvalidation lib) does work, but, how do I wire it to the logger? For example, when the input is empty, I want the logger to keep that piece of information, what should I do?

[image: metadata page screenshot]

Update:
I went back to my code and I found that if I change my DTO Testrequest it works. Specifically, the following works.

```
namespace web
{
[Api("Test request")]
[Route("/test/{Input}", "GET")]
[Route("/test")]
public class TestRequest : IReturn<TestResponse>
{
    [ApiMember(Name = "Parameter name", Description = "Parameter Description",
    ParameterType = "body", DataType = "string", IsRequired = true)]
    public string Input { get; set; }
}
public class TestResponse
{
    public string Output { get; set; }
}
}
```

and this doesn't

```
[Api("Test request")]
[Route("/test/{Input}", "GET")]
[Route("/test")]
public class TestRequest : IReturn<TestResponse>
{
    [ApiMember(Name = "Parameter name", Description = "Parameter Description",
    ParameterType = "body", DataType = "string", IsRequired = true)]
    public string Input { get; set; }
}
public class TestResponse
{
    public string Output { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Please include the full class definition of TestRequest unmodified

Comment: @mythz updated, now it has full definition. I've also asked another question about how to export fluentvalidation results to logger

Comment: I've just created an example .NET Core project which is working as expected, so you'll need to upgrade to latest version if you haven't already, if there's still an issue publish a stand-alone verifiable example on GitHub and I'll check it out. Please open new questions to ask unrelated questions, but you can use `ValidationFeature.ErrorResponseFilter` hook to intercept and customize error response DTOs.

Comment: @mythz thanks!! great help!

Answer (score 0):

I've just created [NetCoreApps/scratch](https://github.com/NetCoreApps/scratch) project to test your TestRequest Service:

```
[Api("Test request")]
[Route("/test/{Input}", "GET")]
[Route("/test")]
public class TestRequest : IReturn<TestResponse>
{
    [ApiMember(Name = "Parameter name", Description = "Parameter Description",
        ParameterType = "body", DataType = "string", IsRequired = true)]
    public string Input { get; set; }
}
public class TestResponse
{
    public string Output { get; set; }
}

public class MyServices : Service
{
    public object Any(TestRequest request) => new TestResponse();
}
```

Which is working as expected using the latest v1.0.41 of .NET Core on NuGet:

[image]

So you'll need to upgrade if you're not using the latest version of .NET Core.

Comment: after I tried yours which works, I went back to my code and I finally found the difference. Not because my dotnet core version, but rather strange. It seems that DTO class should be in the same name space as service.cs does. I've updated my question.

Comment: I think that if dto class is incorrect because of the inconsistency (in the same namespace with service.cs or not) and it doesn't work then I can understand. Problem is it works in all other areas except for the mentioned behavior.

Comment: @shawhu I've [moved the DTOs to a different namespace](https://github.com/NetCoreApps/scratch/commit/928b8b0e1c8860c2fc78bf2844624c1e59b4c0ff) and it still works as expected, if the issue is because you forgot to put a namespace, just add one.

Comment: No, I don't think I "forgot" to put a namespace. A class or DTO class shouldn't only work in a namespace. A namespace is created only to make sure different classes with the same naming won't cause conflict when used in the same project. A DTO class by definition, won't have the same problem because it's brand new for each and every project. Or, maybe it IS a requirement for  building servicestack DTO class and if that's so, I admit I didn't know, still not forgetting but merely ignorance. Now I know.

Comment: @shawhu You absolutely should always have a namespace when building any non throwaway .NET App, the only time it's really acceptable not to have one is for c# scripts.